# What is val function and what does this ‴return $('#q').val();‴ mean in this code?

Tags: g1ant

Is it like val function is predefined?

code:

```
selenium.open chrome url msn.com timeout 30000
list.create text aa result ♥list
selenium.callfunction search q by id functionname val parameters ♥list type jquery
selenium.runscript script ‴return $('#q').val();‴
dialog ♥result
```

Answer (score 1):

`val()` is a method in jQuery that lets you set or get the value of a given HTML element ([Documentation here](https://api.jquery.com/val/)). `#q` is the ID of the search field over at msn.com, so what that script does is it retrieves the value typed out in that field. Since it's usually empty when the site is just loaded up, you would get an empty dialog box when calling `dialog ♥result`.

Comment: really helpful.

Comment: but when I m using selenium.callfunction command I guess there I am passing the value of list as a parameter and changing the value of q i.e. search box, then it should show me text aa.